# The Shortcut Ctrl+E,D won't work in vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a css file in my project. Ctrl+E,D formatted my code in vs. but only in this file won't work.
When I press this shortcut an error was shown:

> Specified argument was out of the range of values. Parameter name:
>   charToReplace

Also in this css file, undo won't work!!!
Why?

Comment: This seems like a bug in visual studio. You could search their bug db and if you don't find anything, file one (and attach the file that you're trying to format).

Comment: I do, but my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

AS I said in my comment, this seems like a visual studio bug. If you're looking for a workaround, you could try a formatter like this: http://www.cleancss.com/

Also, check if you have any extensions installed that might change how formatting is done.